# Change Gnome-Panel profile at startup according to number of displays

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, gnome-panel

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 on a Laptop. 
I have a startup script which enables external displays, if they are connected. It runs at GDM startup, configured in `/etc/gdm/Init/Default`.

When i'm running without external displays, Gnome should use 2 Panels.
When i'm using 2 external displays, Gnome should add an additional Panel to the second display. But this should of course be removed again if i detach the external displays (and restart).

Can i configure this use case by using Gnome Panel-profiles?
I read that there is a startup option "--profile" for gnome-panel, but i don't know how and where i could switch the profile, especially because this has to be done after recognizing the number of displays.

Or can i add a general Gnome profile and switch between those profiles somehow to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Thinking about trying to use gconftool-2 for this use case. Will post here when it works and how